# How to pass HashSet type into method

Tags: c#, hashset

I have two different classes Student and Teacher in C#. Instances of these classes are stored in separated HashSets. Both classes are interited from class Human.

```
HashSet<Student> students
HashSet<Teacher> teachers
```

I would like to pass them into one method to sort them/print them, like

```
Sort(students);
Sort(teachers);
private void SortPeople<T>(HashSet<T> people)
{
  // ... sorting function
}
```

But that does not work, the collection people in sorting function does not recognize it (cannot see atributes of Students/Teachers).
What would be the right solution?
Thank you.

Comment: Do `Students` and `Teachers` inherit a common ancestor? If yes, add `where T : TheCommonAncestor`. If no, how do you plan on sorting the collections? Also, keep in mind that `HashSet` has no order. So, you might want the method to _return_ a `List` or something.

Comment: As a side note, why are you using plural names for those type names? A collection of Student**s** named `students` doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Right, my fault while writing it. I will edit it.

Comment: instead of implementing an explicitly sort method, you could take advantage of IComparable And IComparer Interface https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-the-icomparable-and-icomparer-interface-in-c-sharp/

Answer (score 0):

My sugestion is for you to use an interface for the generic ...

```
void SortPeople<T>(HashSet<T> people) 
    where T : IPeople
{
    
}




public class Student : IPeople
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher : IPeople
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IPeople
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```